# Como eu consigo fazer a rotação suavizada na Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Olá! Estou testando uma movimentação em 2D, estilo plataforma. Basicamente, quero que quando o jogador aperte "A", ele gire para a direita. Eu Consegui fazer isso, mas quero que ele se rotacione girando, não apenas do nada ele já virar para a direita....

```
    [Header("Main")]
    public int Speed;

    [Header("Inputs")]
    float HorizontalInput;

    [Header("Others")]
    Rigidbody2D Rig;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();

        Rotate();
    }

    void Move()
    {
        HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Rig.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalInput * Speed, Rig.velocity.y);
    }

    void Rotate()
    {
        if(HorizontalInput > 0)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, HorizontalInput * 0, 0);
        }

        if(HorizontalInput < 0)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, HorizontalInput * (180 * -1), 0);
        }
    }
```

Tentei esse Script, ele está virando para a esquerda normalmente, mas quando eu viro para a direita, ele já vai direto... (Tente colocar esse código na Unity para entender melhor, tentei colocar um vídeo mas parece que não é possível no StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Os computadores possuem processadores que fazem bilhões de operações por segundo, seguindo essa lógica quando você roda um código que está em um ciclo infinito (Update) ele irá fazer aquilo MUITAS vezes por segundo, tão rápido que parece que ele teleporta...

Para corrigir isso em qualquer situação de movimentação para ser mais realista você precisa multiplicar por Time.deltaTime é um número bem baixo que vai depender da velocidade da sua máquina, fazendo com que ele fique em valores mais "suaves".

Vou só dar um exemplo de como você poderia fazer.

```cs
Rig.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime, Rig.velocity.y);
```

E outra coisa porque está pegando Input Horizontal e multiplicando por 0? Isso vai sempre resultar em 0, por isso ele não rotaciona do outro lado...

Último ponto importante a função

```cs
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, HorizontalInput * (180 * -1), 0);
```

vai atribuir a rotação em [Eulers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) diretamente ao transform, você não está pegando a rotação atual e somando valores. Para rotacionar relativo à posição atual você poderia utilizar a função [Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html).

Caso na verdade você queira somente uma movimentação única com interpolação você pode usar setar diretamente o [EulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) usando [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html).

Recomendo que antes de tudo faça tutoriais para iniciantes, tem uns muito bons no youtube e também sempre que tiver em dúvida olhar a documentação da Unity que é muito bem feita e completa.

Answer (score -3):

Para fazer a rotação suavizada na Unity, você pode usar a função Lerp (Linear Interpolation) do Quaternion. Isso permite que você interpole suavemente entre duas rotações, criando uma transição suave e natural.

Por exemplo, se você quiser fazer um objeto girar gradualmente em direção a um ponto específico, você pode usar a função Quaternion.LookRotation para obter a rotação desejada e, em seguida, usar a função Quaternion.Lerp para interpolar suavemente entre a rotação atual e a rotação desejada.

Aqui está um exemplo de código que mostra como fazer isso:

```
public class SmoothRotation : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;

    void Update () {
        // Obtemos a rotação desejada
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position);

        // Interpolamos suavemente entre a rotação atual e a rotação desejada
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5);
    }
}
```

Neste exemplo, a rotação do objeto é atualizada a cada quadro, fazendo com que ele gire gradualmente em direção ao objeto alvo. O valor Time.deltaTime * 5 controla a velocidade da interpolação - quanto maior o valor, mais rápido será a transição.

Comment: [Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT não é permitido na rede](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-na-rede?cb=1)